# Deploy a .rar on cloudfoundry using eclipse plugin

Tags: java, database, servlets, cloud-foundry

I am currently using the cloudfoundry eclipse plugin to deploy my JSP/Servlet web application. My application is now using a Db (Sqlite). However I am having problem deploying the sqlitejdbc.rar to cloudfoundry (all i do to update the application is right click on my application under VMware Cloud-foundry server and select update. But that doesn't seem to work and i get an exception saying that it cant find the rar file.
In my local system i simply paste the sqlitejdb.rar to the lib directory of Tomcat and when i run the webapp locally it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you place the sqlitejdbc.rar file into your lib directory (inside your WEB-INF directory) that should get deployed as part of your application into cloudfoundry and become accessible.

You can also try to deploy your app using vmc push to see what errors you get from vmc.
I also recommend looking at the log files on cloudfoundry.com